# jQuery - Select a option based on what link has been paste in input link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, select

In my form, I have a `input tag` & a `select tag`. My `input tag` will always have a **link** be pasted in, while my `select tag` will have all **domains** that user has added to their account.

*My form:*

```
<form action="/action">
  # Link will be paste here
  <input type="text" name="link" id="link">

  # User will select one of their domains
  <select id="user-domains">
    <option value="1">google.com</option>
    <option value="2">facebook.com</option>
    <option value="3">stackoverflow.com</option>
    <option value="4">github.com</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What I want to achieve is, when user paste a link into `input#link`, if the **link** contains one of my `select options` text, that `option` will be selected.

*For instance:*

**1)** User paste inn `https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow/` & `option` that has **facebook.com** as its text, will be selected.

**2)** User paste inn `https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp` & since none of my `options` has **www.w3schools.com** as its text, nothing will be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The little function below should do exactly what you want.

```
function change () {
    input = $('#link').val();

    // Loop through all the options
    $('#user-domains option').each(function(){

        // Check if the input string contains the text from the current option
        if(input.indexOf($(this).html()) >=0){
            // Set the correct value to the select box
            $('#user-domains').val($(this).val());
        }
    });
}
```

With onChange event as follows

`<input onchange="change()" type="text" name="link" id="link">`

check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mvns4nxa/)

**Edit**

I also created a JSfiddle for the `onPaste` event. Because the `onPaste` event fires before the value in the input is updated I had to use a `setTimeout` to make sure the change function is run after the input has changed.

`<input onpaste="setTimeout(function(){change()},0)" type="text" name="link" id="link">`

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24mmvtq6/1/) for the onpaste event.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```
if (str_link.toLowerCase().indexOf("facebook") >= 0) {
// select facebook option
// ... else if(other options) ...
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This is how you can do it in javascript if jQuery is not required, for somebody who is just learning.
```

```js
function handleDropDown(data) {
            var elem = document.getElementById('user-domains');
            var optionList = elem.options;

            for (var i = 0; i < optionList.length; i++) {
                var currentOption = optionList[i];
                if (data.indexOf(currentOption.textContent) >=0) {
                    elem.selectedIndex = currentOption.index;
                    break;//Exit the loop ASAP
                }
                
            }
           
        }
```

```html
<form action="/action">
  # Link will be paste here
  <input type="text" name="link" id="link" onchange="handleDropDown(this.value)">

  # User will select one of their domains
  <select id="user-domains">
    <option value="1">google.com</option>
    <option value="2">facebook.com</option>
    <option value="3">stackoverflow.com</option>
    <option value="4">github.com</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```